# Chained coroutine task example segfaults

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-coroutine, compiler-explorer

In "C++20 - The Complete Guide", Josuttis uses the following code to show how making a coroutine implement the interface of an awaiter makes it possible for it to store sub-coroutines that are resumed automatically when the outer coroutine is resumed. I have understood the explanation and the code (I think), but surprisingly enough, when I compile and launch the code:

```bash
g++ -std=c++20 corocorosub.cpp -O3 -o corocorosub && ./corocorosub
```

I get a segfault error:

```
MAIN: callCoro() initialized
  callCoro(): CALL coro()
MAIN: callCoro() suspended
    coro(): PART1
MAIN: callCoro() suspended
    coro(): PART2
MAIN: callCoro() suspended
  callCoro(): coro() done
MAIN: callCoro() suspended
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Even more surprisingly, on [Compile Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rz8qhzsMx) it works just fine.

I have no clue what could be wrong, and *where* (the code, or the compiler).

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

class [[nodiscard]] CoroTaskSub {
 public:
  struct promise_type;
  using CoroHdl = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
 private:
  CoroHdl hdl;

 public:
  struct promise_type {
    CoroHdl subHdl = nullptr;

    auto get_return_object() {
      return CoroTaskSub{CoroHdl::from_promise(*this)};
    }
    auto initial_suspend() { return std::suspend_always{}; }
    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
    void return_void() { }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_always{}; }
  };

  CoroTaskSub(auto h)
   : hdl{h} {
  }
  ~CoroTaskSub() {
    if (hdl) {
      hdl.destroy();
    }
  }
  CoroTaskSub(const CoroTaskSub&) = delete;
  CoroTaskSub& operator=(const CoroTaskSub&) = delete;

  bool resume() const {
    if (!hdl || hdl.done()) {
      return false;
    }
    CoroHdl innerHdl = hdl;
    while (innerHdl.promise().subHdl && !innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()) {
      innerHdl = innerHdl.promise().subHdl;
    }
    innerHdl.resume();         
    return !hdl.done();
  }

  bool await_ready() { return false; }
  void await_suspend(auto awaitHdl) {
    awaitHdl.promise().subHdl = hdl;
  }
  void await_resume() {}
};

CoroTaskSub coro()
{
  std::cout << "    coro(): PART1\n";
  co_await std::suspend_always{};
  std::cout << "    coro(): PART2\n";
}

CoroTaskSub callCoro()
{
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): CALL coro()\n";
  co_await coro();
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): coro() done\n";
  co_await std::suspend_always{};
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): END\n";
}

int main()
{
  auto coroTask = callCoro();
  std::cout << "MAIN: callCoro() initialized\n";

  while (coroTask.resume()) {
    std::cout << "MAIN: callCoro() suspended\n";
  }

  std::cout << "MAIN: callCoro() done\n";
}
```

Comment: [ASAN is your friend](https://godbolt.org/z/sGrGjePYY). The issue here is that `coro()`'s frame is destroyed, but `callCoro()`'s frame is still referring to it and trying to call `done()` on it.

Comment: @Barry, I guess this is UB, then, right? For me it is actually manifesting on the line `innerHdl.resume();`, with `innerHdl` poiting to the destroyed `coro()`, which in turn means that the first mistake is calling using `innerHdl.promise().subHdl`, which is a destroyed handle, in the `while`. Adding `innerHdl.promise().subHdl = nullptr;` right after the `while` loop fixes the issue, or it seems to. It looks reasonable to me, as it amounts to _"if `innerHdl` is the deepest coro, there's no deeper coro, so set its `subHdl` to `nullptr` just in case it is a dangling one"_. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the "inner" coroutine completes and destroys itself, but the "outer" coroutine doesn't know that this happened, still has a handle to it, and is still trying to access the frame.

The solution is that there somehow needs to be more cooperation between the "inner" and "outer" coroutines. One simple way, though possibly not the best way (I am hardly a coroutine expert), is to have the coroutine promise itself track both its child and its parent:

```cpp
struct promise_type {
    CoroHdl subHdl = nullptr;
    CoroHdl parent = nullptr;
};
```

Where `parent` gets additionally set in `await_suspend` (I went ahead and replaced the `auto` with the type that we know it is):

```cpp
void await_suspend(CoroHdl awaitHdl) {
    awaitHdl.promise().subHdl = hdl;
    hdl.promise().parent = awaitHdl;
}
```

And `await_resume` removes itself:

```cpp
void await_resume() {
    if (hdl.promise().parent) {
        hdl.promise().parent.promise().subHdl = nullptr;
    }
}
```

You can see that this is [ASAN-clean](https://godbolt.org/z/7oxoWM7P4), because now the "outer" coroutine will cease to have a child when the "inner" one completes.

A different way to do this, what `std::generator` is specified to do, is to have `final_suspend` return a distinct awaiter. You can see its reference implementation [here](https://godbolt.org/).

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of investigating, I've found a couple of other (sub-optimal) ways to fix the issue, ***at least in this specific example***. I hope that can help other readers in exploring this fascinating topic of coroutines!

---

Since the problem is due to the `CoroTaskSub` retuend by `coro()` being destroyed right after the expression `co_await coro();` is completely evaluated, and `callCoro()`'s frame still having the `subHdl` pointing to it and *using* it via `innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()`, one solution is to give a name to `coro()` to keep it alive for as long as the `callCoro()` is alive:

```cpp
CoroTaskSub callCoro()
{
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): CALL coro()\n";
  auto Coro = coro();
  co_await Coro;
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): coro() done\n";
  co_await std::suspend_always{};
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): END\n";
}
```

This means that

- the `subHdl` of `callCoro()`'s will always point to something valid, and `.done()` will keep returning `true` for it, so that the body of the `while` will not be executing, `innerHdl` will resolve to `hdl`, and no attempt to resume `coro()` will be made after it reaches the final suspend point;
- on the other hand, the solution above undesirably keep `coro()` alive more than it needs to be.

---

Another way is to set `subHdl` back to `nullptr` as soon as it is `.done()`:

```cpp
    while (innerHdl.promise().subHdl && !innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()) {
      innerHdl = innerHdl.promise().subHdl;
    }
    if (innerHdl.promise().subHdl && innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()) {
        innerHdl.promise().subHdl = nullptr;
    }
```

This way, next time `.resume()` is called for `coroTask` (i.e. `callCoro()`), it will not execute the body of the `while`, just like no sub-coroutine had ever been set.

To be precise, since going past the `while` means that either `innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()` was `true`, or  `innerHdl.promise().subHdl` was `nullptr` in the first place, the `if` is actually redundant, and we can just do this:

```cpp
    while (innerHdl.promise().subHdl && !innerHdl.promise().subHdl.done()) {
      innerHdl = innerHdl.promise().subHdl;
    }
    innerHdl.promise().subHdl = nullptr;
```

After all, once we've got to the deepest `innerHdl` not-`done()` yet, we know that *its* `subHdl` is either `.done()` or `nullptr` as it was never set in the first place, in which case setting it to `nullptr` unconditionally should be just fine.