# Weird behavior of CodeLLDB when debugging C++ coroutines

Tags: c++, debugging, c++20, c++-coroutine, codelldb

As far as my experience goes, a breakpoint on a given line of code means that the first time the debugger breaks on that line, *nothing* of that line has been executing yet. Or, in other words, when the debugger stops at a breakpoint, it stops there *before* executing that line of code, not *after it* or *in the middle of it*.

And I don't think I had ever seen this view to be contraddicted (despite my experience is mostly on C++, and so that's what I've been always debugging).

However, this seems not to be the case when coroutines are involved.

Take [this code from a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75827750/5825294) (it is broken because the code has UB, but the issue I'm describing occurs before that is triggered, so it doesn't matter), a target excerpt of which is here:

```cpp
class [[nodiscard]] CoroTaskSub {
  …
 public:
  …
  CoroTaskSub(auto h)
   : hdl{h} {
  }
  …
};
CoroTaskSub coro() {
  …
}

CoroTaskSub callCoro() {
  std::cout << "  callCoro(): CALL coro()\n";
  co_await coro();
  …
}
```

I've done the following:

1. put a breakpoint at the `cout` line
2. put a breakpoint at the `co_await` line
3. run the program (at this point the debugger stops at the first of those two breakpoints)
4. put a breakpoint at the line `: hdl{h} {`, i.e. in the constructor of the `CoroTaskSub` class¹
5. continue with the program

At this point I expected that the debugger woudl break at the breakpoint on the `co_await` line, before anything of that line is evaluated, but instead it breaks a the breakpoint on `CoroTaskSub`'s constructor, just like the `coro()` is being processed already.

That's a bit weird, no?

Do you know why that happens?

---

(¹) Because of how the program is structured, the control has already passed once here, upon the call `callCoro()` that is done in `main`, but I've put the breakpoint only here because I wanted to see when this constructor is called to construct `coro()`'s `CoroTaskSub`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in a regular function, in a coroutine function, creating the return value object is the *first thing* that happens (well, after creating the promise and a few book-keeping things). This is before any line of code in the coroutine, before even the `initial_suspend` point. This is done by calling the promise's `get_return_object` function.

This is necessary because the return value object needs to be a valid object to the caller in the event that the `initial_suspend` point *suspends*.

Comment: That tells me why `callCoro()`'s `CoroTaskSub` gets created even before the execution hits the `cout` line. But it doesn't tell me why `coro()`'s `CoroTaskSub` is constructed even before I hit the line `co_await coro();`. I mean I'm not saying that I should enter `coro`'s body before the creation of its `CoroTaskSub`, but that I expected the debugger to stop at the `co_await` line before _anything_ about it is even considered.